# regex for this rule?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex for this rule:

> "Must contain minimum 3 and maximum 5
>   numeric chars. The same character can
>   be repeated max. 5 times! Also, the length should be minim 10 chars."

Do you have any ideea?

I started with this:

```
^\d{3,5}$
```

but this does restrict to have min. 3 decimals one after other and what I need is the possibility to have them intercalated with letters also (min. 3 and max 5 occurrences).

Can you give a helping hand please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible in regex, but the need of backreference is going to make it very slow.

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){3,5}\D*$)(?!.*(.)(?:.*\1){4}).{10,}
```

Description:

- `(?=(?:\D*\d){3,5}\D*$)`: Ensure there is 3 to 5 numerals
- `(?!.*(.)(?:.*\1){4})`: Ensure there is *not* 5 copies on the same character
- `.{10,}`: Ensure the matched string's length is at least 10.

An easier way is to use a `Dictionary<char, int>` and tally the characters.

Answer (score 3):

All of these conditions (except length) are extremely unsuited to regular expressions. Unsuited as in: it will take an exponential-size expression. Use normal programming methods instead to count letters, numbers and repetition. - unless this is homework for Regular Expressions 500, there is no point whatsoever in using a regex.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that doing with regex is nicer from a clean code perspective, but I agree with what you said.

Comment: @Cristian: No, a complex regex is very dirty.